# MVC 4 - DataAnnotations - Validation for Type

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have the following code working

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Price is required.")]
    [Range(typeof(Decimal), "1", "9999", ErrorMessage = "Price xx.xx")]
    public decimal? productPrice { get; set; }
```

When the page is submitted with 
Price = EMPTY Field error message is "Price is required.".
Price = over 9999 error message is "Price xx.xx".

However, when I type 'aaaa' the error message is 
**"The field productPrice must be a number."**

How can I change the message if type in not correct?
Like : "Price must be a decimal/number between 1-9999.

**---- UPDATE: ----**
The below code worked with

NULL, Not Decimal, Between Range, BUT not working with ".1".

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Price is required.")]
    [RegularExpression(@"[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+", ErrorMessage = "Price must be a Numbers only.")]
    [Range(typeof(Decimal), "1", "9999", ErrorMessage = "Price must be a decimal/number between {1} and {2}.")]
    public decimal? productPrice { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try with the regular expression:

```
[RegularExpression(@"[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+", ErrorMessage = "{0} must be a Number.")]
```

you can also try the Data Annotations Extensions:
http://dataannotationsextensions.org/Home/Wiki

Or write your own implementation,something like this :
https://github.com/srkirkland/DataAnnotationsExtensions/blob/master/DataAnnotationsExtensions/DigitsAttribute.cs

**UPDATE**
With REGEX (Matches $9,999.99 | $0.70 | .1)

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\$?([1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,2}(\,[0-9]{3})*(\.[0-9]{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,}(\.[0-9]{0,2})?|0(\.[0-9]{0,2})?|(\.[0-9]{1,2})?)$", ErrorMessage = "{0} must be a Number.")]
```

Or using Range with a slight modification to @Martin suggestion (actually is a better solution):

```
[Range(typeof(Decimal), "0", "9999", ErrorMessage = "{0} must be a decimal/number between {1} and {2}.")]
```

Comment: This regular expression will fail in various cases such ".1" I do not recommend using regular expressions to crunch numbers. regular expressions are meant for matching strings (text) input. RangeAttribute is the most appropriate way to solve this problem.

Comment: @JOBG as Martin said, ".1" is NOT being caught by either one of the (3) DataAnnotations. Any thoughts?

Comment: Just change @MartinDevillers Range method from 1-999 to 0-999 and it should let pass ".1", as i said actually Range is a better solution. I also added a regex in case you want to check with that.

Comment: Neither the RegEx or Range(typeof) is allowing the ".1" example. :(
Still looking around.

Comment: Try changing the property type from `Decimal?` to `string`, it seems like the client side validation does not like ".1" like values, so the work around i found is to change the type to string and afterwards cast it to decimal  when you pass the value from `viewmodel` -> `model` (it should be safe to cast at this point because its already validated by `Range` or `Regex`). The other way would be to disable client side validation for numbers.

Answer (score 5):

First off, I think you will want to change your Range attribute to

```
[Range(typeof(Decimal), "1", "9999", ErrorMessage = "{0} must be a decimal/number between {1} and {2}.")]
```

[According to MSDN,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679255.aspx) this is the valid way to use RangeAttribute.

Second:

> "The field productPrice must be a number."

This is actually unobtrusive client-side JavaScript validation kicking in. Your range validator will fire after the number has been validated. You can disable the number validator although I do not recommend this:

```
$.validator.methods.number = function (n, t) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This will not validate strings with starting digit 0, such as 0007, 0500

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be tripping over a bug in jQuery. That validation is fighting the stuff emitted for your validation attributes.

I have the following property:

```
[Display(ResourceType = typeof(TaxSetupResources), Name = "Model_Value")]
[RegularExpression(@"(^\d+$)|(^\.\d{1,4}$)|(^\d*\.\d{0,4}$)", ErrorMessageResourceName="Model_InvalidFormatForAmount", ErrorMessageResourceType=typeof(TaxSetupResources))]
public decimal? Value { get; set; }
```

Used in a view like this:

```
<div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.Tiers[i].Value, new { title = @Resources.TaxSetupResources.Model_ValueTip })
    <br />@Html.ValidationMessageFor(t => t.Tiers[i].Value)
</div>
```

Just by itself, a value "foo" yields my error message.  A value 0.075 is accepted.  A value of .075 yields "The field Value must be a number", the same issue you seem to be having.

based on [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276531/decimal-is-not-validated-correctly-in-mvc-3-with-jquery-validator), I added the following in document ready:

```
$(function () {
    $.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
        return parseFloat(value).toString() !== "NaN";
    }
});
```

Now I only get my error message, and only when expected (.075 is accepted).